# ComponentDidMount local state update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `someId` that I am getting trough the props and I have `otherId` in the state. Doing this causes infinite loop. I want that if it is the same id to `setState`, if it's not to do nothing.
How can I achieve this?

```
 componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
         if (prevProps.someId === this.state.otherId) {
             this.setState({ ... });
         }
    }
```

Comment: What's inside the `setState` call?

Comment: My guess is that since you call `setState`, the component will update again, thus calling the function again endlessly. What are you trying to achieve exactly and in what conditions ?

Comment: You need to also check that `prevProps.someId !== this.props.someId`, because I assume you only want this to trigger when the prop has changed.

Comment: The prop is not changing, the state is changing. I want to update the state only when the this.state.otherId is the same as this.props.someId.

Answer (score 1):

```
componentDidUpdate(props) {
     if (props.someId !== this.state.otherId) {
             this.setState({ otherId: props.someId });
     }
}
```

I assume you meant to say:
I want that if props.someId is the same as this.state.someId do nothing, if it's not, set it to it...? Or if you want them to be different then just change `!==` back to `===`.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that since you call `setState`, the component will update again, thus calling the function again endlessly.

Maybe you should use `shouldComponentUpdate()` instead.

```js
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    return this.props.someId === nextProps.otherId
}
```

This way, the component will update only if the ids are the same.